# group list of dictionaries by key and create monthly timeline for each key counting each month

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, grouping, timeline

Imagine having this list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'id': 1, 'upload_date': '05-01-2019'}, {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '06-01-2019'}, {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '08-02-2020'}, {'id': 2, 'upload_date': '08-04-2019'}, {'id': 3, 'upload_date': '06-01-2019'}]
```

Output list of dictionaries:

```
[{'id': 1, 'upload_date': '05-01-2019'},
 {'id': 3, 'upload_date': '06-02-2019'},
 {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '06-01-2019'},
 {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '08-02-2020'},
 {'id': 2, 'upload_date': '08-04-2019'}]
```

I want to group the list of dictionaries by id and then for each id create a timeline between 1 January 2019 to March 2020. Then for each month within this timeline I want to count how many times the month has occured.

So far, I managed to create a monthly timeline between these two dates with:

```
timeline = pd.date_range('01-01-2019','03-01-2020', freq='MS').strftime("%m-%Y").tolist()
```

Output timeline:

```
['01-2019', '02-2019', '03-2019', '04-2019', '05-2019', '06-2019', '07-2019', '08-2019', '09-2019', '10-2019', '11-2019', '12-2019', '01-2020', '02-2020', '03-2020']
```

So, the desired output should be something like:

```
1 : ['01-2019': 2, '02-2019': '0', '03-2019': 0, '04-2019': 0, ......... ,'02-2020': 1]
2 : ['01-2019': 0, '02-2019': '0', '03-2019': 0, '04-2019': 1, ......... ,'02-2020': 0]
3 : ['01-2019': 0, '02-2019': '1', '03-2019': 0, '04-2019': 0, ......... ,'02-2020': 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I realized you were looking for MM-YYYY counts, not MM-DD-YYYY, the code below should work as desired. Now using datetime to parse the date, and moved the set comprehension down into the big nest.

---

This is not terribly pretty, but it gets the job done. I guarantee there's a more Pythonic way to achieve this.

```py
from datetime import datetime

lst = [
    {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '05-01-2019'},
    {'id': 3, 'upload_date': '06-02-2019'},
    {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '06-01-2019'},
    {'id': 1, 'upload_date': '08-02-2020'},
    {'id': 2, 'upload_date': '08-04-2019'},
]

# Remove day from lst dates
lst = [
    {
        "id": i["id"],
        "upload_date": f'{datetime.strptime(i["upload_date"], "%m-%d-%Y"):%m-%Y}',
    }
    for i in lst
]

# Four layer comprehension
# - id_dates = {i: {dictcomp} for i in {setcomp}}
#   - {dictcomp} = {date: [listcomp].count(date) if same ID}
#     - [listcomp] = [date for date in list if same ID]
#   - {setcomp} = {id for id in list}
id_dates = {
    i: {
        dct["upload_date"]: [d["upload_date"] for d in lst if d["id"] == i].count(
            dct["upload_date"]
        )
        for dct in lst
        if dct["id"] == i
    }
    for i in {i["id"] for i in lst}
}

for _id, counts in id_dates.items():
    print(f"{_id}: {counts}")
```

Output

```
1: {'05-2019': 1, '06-2019': 1, '08-2020': 1}
2: {'08-2019': 1}
3: {'06-2019': 1}
```

You could replace the curly brackets with square pretty easily if that's required.